# why there is enter between this out put ? I trying to get curent user name and make directory path

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm using Process to run OS commands in Linux with flutter  and I want to get current username and make directory path to music by this code but its get me output like this.
the code

```
devloper.log('*********Scaning Directory*********');
var username = await Process.run('whoami', []);
devloper.log(username.stdout);
String path = '/home/${username.stdout}/Music';
```

[image]

this space makes me crazy! where its come and How can I get out put like this
/home/usename/Musci

Comment: remove ".stdout" while assigning path to variable.

Comment: bro I try it but that dosent give me username